# Pre-populate Okta username during SP-initiated SAML SSO

Tags: okta, kentor-authservices

I added support for SAML 2.0 SSO with Okta to my application using Kentor AuthServices .NET package and the first action done by a user is clicking "Login with Okta" button and then being redirected to Okta's sign in page with SAML request token generated by Kentor.

In some scenarios the user email (username in Okta) is already known beforehand and I want to pre-populate the Username textbox on Okta's sign in page with this value.

Is it possible to do that, for example by providing the desired username in SAML request or in the cookies?

Comment: Received response from Okta that this is not possible to do

Answer (score 1):

The SAML standard has support for including a Subject (that is a user name in SAML lingo) in the AuthnRequest. Unfortunately Kentor.AuthServices doesn't support that (yet). There has been some work done (see https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/issues/430) but I don't know the current status.

Then you of course need to check whether Okta supports reading that data.